# PHP/Xdebug Nesting level error

Tags: php, xdebug

Yes I looked at the previous questions in this topic and I still was not able to solve the problem. I tried `ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 5000);` in my script and still Im getting the error. So I will show you what I'm doing to hopefully get some and and get to a resolution.

Basically I running a test with data from my database.

```
include 'testSettings.php';

//get config
$conf = Config::getInstance('sendCsv.php');
$conf->getConfig();

$formatter = new FormatterContext(new CSVFormatter($conf));
$formatter->formatLoads(null);
```

The complain comes when I call `$formatter->formatLoads(null);

So here is FormatterContext()

```
class FormatterContext
{
    private $strategy;

    public function __construct(IFormatter $formater)
    {
        $this->strategy = $formater;
    }

    public function formatLoads()
    {
        return $this->formatLoads();
    }
}
```

The interface:

```
abstract class IFormatter
{
    private $config;
    private $formatted;
    private $fileMaps;
    private $fileRows;

    abstract public function formatLoads($loads);

    public function __construct(Config $conf)
    {
        $this->fileMaps = $conf->__get('fileMaps');
        $this->fileRows = $conf->__get('fileRows');
    }
}
```

The Strategy:

```
class CSVFormatter extends IFormatter
{


    public function formatLoads($loads)
    {
        echo "hello world!\n";
    }
}
```

Now I really don't know what am I doing wrong here. This is the first time I have encounter this error. Beyond nesting level = 5000 I have not tried, I think at that point something is really wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arg! Silly me... In the context class I'm calling the context `formatLoad()` instead of the strategy. Ooops!

The context class should be like:

```
class FormatterContext
{
    private $strategy;

    public function __construct(IFormatter $formater)
    {
        $this->strategy = $formater;
    }

    public function formatLoads()
    {
        // return $this->formatLoads();
        return $this->strategy->formatLoads();
    }
}
```